# Code doesn't run Properly, i don't know what happen. Just copy the existing dev work, And try to run it and getting errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is Function for background image.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

 // // Set Background Image;

// var path = GetBasePath() + "images/bg.jpg";
$('body').css({
    'background': 'url("' + GetBasePath() + '/images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center fixed',
    'background-size': 'cover'
});
```

This is the function used for getting the base path.

```
function GetBasePath() {

// var pageUrl = document.URL;
// var pageUrlParts = pageUrl.split('/');
// var pageUrlPartsLength = pageUrlParts.length;
var neededUrl = '';
var trigger = true;
var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');

neededUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
// neededUrl = pageUrlParts[0];

for (var i = 1; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
    if (trigger) {
        neededUrl = neededUrl + '/' + pathArray[i];
    }
    if (pathArray[i] == bookFolder) {
        trigger = false;
    }

};

// alert(neededUrl);
return neededUrl;
console.log(neededUrl);
```

Every thing works good but expect this extra basepath that i didn't want.

This is the inspect element code. And have extra basepath. Like ip-screen.html

```
<body style="background: 
url(&quot;http://localhost/TeacherGuide/Human_Systems_Interactions/ip-screen.html/images/bg.jpg&quot;)
 center center / cover no-repeat fixed;">
```

This will work fine if i remove ip-screen.html manually, but i don't know how to do this in js function. Need help. Any one?

Comment: `patharray.pop()`

Comment: Tried .pop(); before the array. but this will kill other parts of website. Like the existing part effect after i write this.

Comment: You mentioned you copied it, have you checked the path is correct?

Comment: Then write another function??

Comment: No i didn't, Kindly guide me how to check it and resolve it?

Comment: @JonasW. Would you tell me, write same function with different name will work for me ?

Answer (score 0):

As I Understand, please replace "ip-screen.html" from URL like below

```
 var z="http://localhost/TeacherGuide/Human_Systems_Interactions/ip-screen.html/images/bg.jpg"
 z=z.replace("/ip-screen.html/","/");
 console.log(z);
```